# Include PDF without space on the left

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, include, overpic

I'm trying to include a PDF and then add text to it using overpic:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}% ensure identical page size
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{overpic}[page=1,scale=1,unit=1mm]%
{test.pdf}
\put(25,220){text to put}

\end{overpic}
\end{document}
```

However there is always a little space on the left and the PDF is cutoff an the right. How do I do this with the PDF dead center and scaled 100%?

This is what the compiler gives as an error:

```
Overfull \hbox (14.99... pt to wide) in paragraph line 13--14
```

Comment: Simply put `\hspace*{-17.21907pt}\begin{overpic}[....`

Comment: Simply put `\noindent\begin{overpic}[...`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `overpic` is in a paragrapĥ with indentation. Use `\noindent` to remove this indentation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}% ensure identical page size
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm, bottom=0mm}
\setlength\unitlength{1mm}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{overpic}[page=1,scale=1,unit=1mm]%
{test.pdf}
\put(25,220){text to put}

\end{overpic}
\end{document}
```